# How to remove extra blank characters between letters?

Tags: r

my dataset

```
id   data
1    C H I C A G O  I L
2    M A D I S O N  W I
3    N E W  Y O R K  N Y
```

there is one blank character between letters in a word and 2 blank characters between words. im requiring to remove them

```
id   data
1    CHICAGO IL
2    MADISON WI
3    NEW YORK NY
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(data = str_replace_all(str_remove_all(data, 
      "(?<=\\S)\\s{1}(?=\\S)"), "\\s+", " "))
```

-output

```
id         data
1  1   CHICAGO IL
2  2   MADISON WI
3  3  NEW YORK NY
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, data = c("C H I C A G O  I L", "M A D I S O N  W I", 
" N E W  Y O R K  N Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: What if the strings dont come without spaces between letters? The current code will also kill the space between words: `CHICAGOIL`

Comment: @AndresMora in that case, we may need a condition ie. `df1 %>% mutate(data = case_when(str_detect(data, "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])") ~ data, TRUE ~ str_replace_all(str_remove_all(data, 
      "(?<=\\S)\\s{1}(?=\\S)"), "\\s+", " ")))`

Answer (score 5):

Using `gsub` to remove any space that's followed by a capital letter:

```
df$data <- gsub("\\s(?=[A-Z])", "", df$data, perl = T)
```

**Output**

```
  id        data
1  1  CHICAGO IL
2  2  MADISON WI
3  3 NEW YORK NY
```

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously too much, but the logic behind should be demonstrated:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(data = str_replace_all(data, " ", "0"),
         data = str_replace_all(data, "00", " "),
         data = str_replace_all(data, "0", ""))
```

```
id        data
1  1  CHICAGO IL
2  2  MADISON WI
3  3 NEW YORK NY
```